# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can updata to firebase, so my connection , I think there is no problem with my connection
but I can't retrieve data from firestore.

dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0"
```

code:

```
private TextView showusername;
private TextView showpassword;
private TextView showphone;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference memRef = db.collection("Member");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal);
    showusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    showpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    showphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    memRef.whereEqualTo("name","王小名")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                        Member mem = documentSnapshot.toObject(Member.class);
                        String name = mem.getName();
                        String password = mem.getPassword();
                        String phone = mem.getPhone();
                        showusername.setText(name);
                        showpassword.setText(password);
                        showphone.setText(phone);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

logcat:

2020-02-24 14:32:08.625 3747-3840/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER

I just add

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

into my dependencies

but it fail when sycning then build shows

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0] C:\Users\jack0\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e40595c3c511248facbf0e003354fb90\jetified-firebase-messaging-20.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.messaging" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated. Use `FirebaseMessagingService` instead. You should use latest dependency of messaging like `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0`

Comment: how? I google it yesterday, but I still fail